# Given a matrix of pairwise orderings, how to enumerate all possible total orders

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a 2d matrix, `Pairwise[i][j]`, where the `[i][j]` entry is

(a)`1` if the `i`th element is "less" than the `j`th element,

(b)`0` if the `i`th element is "equal to" the `j`th element, and

(c)`-1` if the `i`th element is neither "less" than nor "equal to" the `j`th element.

What is the efficient way to enumerate all possible subsets of total orderings?

E.g., if [2][3] = 1, [2][4] = 1, [4][3] = 1, then I would like to be able to enumerate the following:

2->3

2->4

2->4->3

... and so on.

Comment: @DmytroDadyka the ith element refers to a struct elsewhere and it does not refer to the numerical index.

Comment: "neither less than nor equal to" Can you clarify this? Is it "greater", then, or are your elements only partially ordered? Also, do you want to include equalities in your total orderings?

Comment: @Nelfeal neither less than nor equal to could be greater than or also incomparable. Both situations are subsumed under "neither less than nor equal to"

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [transitive closure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure). I'm not sure what you mean by "all possible subsets of total orderings"; you title lead me to think you were looking for something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix can be seen as a directed graph where element `i` is a direct predecessor of element `j` if `Pairwise[i][j] = 1`. Simply run a search algorithm (most likely a depth-first search) to enumerate all paths.
Ignore the `-1` values, since they either do not contribute to a path or represent a "greater than" relation that already has a corresponding `1` value elsewhere.
If you include equalities in the total orderings (by treating the `0` values as `1`s), you would have a infinite number of paths, so ignore `0`s as well.

Comment: Ignoring equality will lead to ignoring certain valid transitive chains, if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: @rici Can you give an example? As I understand it, if you had say `[2][3] = 0`, then you would also have `[3][2] = 0`, and could never enumerate all orderings containing `2` and `3` (for instance, `2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2` would be one).

Comment: you'd need to use a transitive closure or shortest path algorithm; a naive DFS won't do it. Example: [1][2] = 0; [2][3] = 1. Correct result is 1->3, but ignoring [1][2] = 0 won't generate it.

Comment: @rici I don't think you understood me. If you have `[1][2] = 0`, by definition of equality, you should have `[2][1] = 0` as well. Which means you would indeed get `1 -> 2 -> 3`, but also `1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3` and so on. Where do you stop?

Comment: @nefleal: I understand you perfectly. You stop when you visit a node the second time. Please read any standard algo text on the algorithms I mentioned. (And/or explain to me how your approach would produce 1->3 from my example.)

Comment: @rici Alright, I guess it depends if you want a strict ordering or not, and if you don't, what equality means in this situation. My approach wouldn't produce your example because it assumes OP wants a strict ordering. If he doesn't, and if equality means that the two elements are the same (not just that they compare equal), then he might as well simplify the matrix beforehand.

Comment: It doesn't require equality to mean the same, just that it is transitive with less-than. If equivalence classes aren't transitive, then total ordering is probably impossible. (And that's the other way to do it: first use a strongly-connected components algorithm to find the equivalence classes, and then do the DFS on the reduced graph.) (You still need cycle detection unless you are 100% convinced that the user input is valid. Oh, look, that's the shuttle exploding.)

Answer (score 1):

Basic on a comment stream from a different answer, I propose the following algorithm:

1. Construct the equivalence classes based on the "equality" relationship using the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)#Algorithms) algorithm. The algorithm involves a simple depth-first (or breadth-first) search in which you only consider links whose heads are less than their tails. (That is, you only follow the link `i -> j` if `i < j`.) Since you might not be able to guarantee that the matrix is symmetrical, you might want to check both directions, using `Pairwise[i][j] == 0 || Pairwise[j][j] == 0`. Each component is labeled with the smallest index of any element in the component (often called the "representative"). The output of this step is a mapping from indexes to representatives, which is a simple vector.
2. Construct a reduced graph by folding together all "less than" entries between two components into a single relationship between components.
3. Perform a [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) on the reduced graph, by doing a depth-first scan *with cycle detection*. (The DFS will be similar to that in a [topogical sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Algorithms).